# Is coupling the router state logic to a model wrong?

Tags: model-view-controller, coding-style, ember.js

Take for example:

```
Ember.Model.reopen({
  show: Ember.observer( function(){
    var target = this.get( 'showPath' ),
        waypoint = Ember.Route.transitionTo( 'root' ),
        destination = Ember.Route.transitionTo( target ),
        router = App.get( 'router' );

    waypoint( router );
    destination( router, this );
  })
});

App.Post.reopen({
  showPath: 'posts.show'
});
```

Here we have defined a show method on a model which transitions from the current state to the destination, first stopping at root.

I've found this makes code relating to the simple task of showing an object super trivial:

```
App.Post.find(1).show();
```

Putting aside whether this is helpful, my trouble with it is that we have some pretty blatant coupling of the model class to the router.

My question is...

Is this something to worry about?

Answer (score 3):

My instinct is that this is wrong. When you think about the dependency graph of an Ember application, it is clear that the router depends on models and therefore it is better if models do not depend on the router.